# Telegram Bot "START" Button issue on history clean up on iOS devices

Tags: python, ios, bots, telegram, aiogram

Facing issue with my telegram bot using aiogram 3.4.x. Works fine on android devices, but can't find solution for iOS(tested on different iphone devices)

After history cleanup on android devices "START" button available after 5 seconds delay.

On iOS devices history remaining empty and button not appear.
Tested using same devices on other but similar bots, button is appear. As I understand this should be default telegram behavior and have no controls from the bot side.

Use default start handler:

```
@dp.message(CommandStart())
    async def command_start_handler(message: types.Message) -> None:
```

and default bot start:

```
async def main() -> None:
    bot = Bot(TOKEN, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)
```